# Google Cloud Translation API The request is missing a valid API key

Tags: android, google-translate, google-translation-api, google-cloud-iam

I'm trying to use the Google Cloud Translation API in my application but whenever I try to translate something it comes up with this missing valid API error.

I've done the [quickstart steps](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart) and that didn't work.

I've tried the steps in the [client library authentication](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries) and that hasn't worked either.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: herrsa1.bit.translator, PID: 16598
com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateException: The request is missing a valid API key.

  at com.google.cloud.translate.spi.v2.HttpTranslateRpc.translate(HttpTranslateRpc.java:61)
  .. 18 more
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden

  {
    "code" : 403,
    "errors" : [{
      "domain" : "global",
      "message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",
      "reason" : "forbidden"
    }],
    "message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }

  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
  ... 4 more
  at com.google.cloud.translate.spi.v2.HttpTranslateRpc.translate(HttpTranslateRpc.java:130)
  ... 19 more
```

Comment: can you share your sample code

Answer (score 6):

If you are using client library and you have already downloaded your service account json file, try doing this:

```js
// Instantiates a client
const translate = new Translate({
    projectId: 'your project id', //eg my-proj-0o0o0o0o'
    keyFilename: 'path of your service acount json file' //eg my-proj-0fwewexyz.json
});
```

instead of this:

```js
// Instantiates a client
const translate = new Translate({projectId});
```

This way you need only your the service acount json file and the specific API enabled

Answer (score 2):

The error on API key means you didn't create or use the key properly. You need to do the following for the key to work:

1. [Create a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts)
2. [Create a key for above service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys)
3. Download the key to a location, for example, a local path
4. Set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the file path of the key, refer to samples in Quickstart tutorial

I'd reccomend doing #1 & #2 in GCP Console, and handling #3 & #4 in Cloud Shell.

Answer (score 0):

*I also tried to execute [this](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries) sample program.
I followed the [same](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries) instruction. But when I executing I got same error(The request is missing a valid API key).*

**I changed a line in the sample program.**

Instead of

```
Translate translate = TranslateOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
```

I added

```
Translate translate = TranslateOptions
            .newBuilder()
            .setCredentials(
                ServiceAccountCredentials
                            .fromStream(new FileInputStream(
                                    "YourCredentialFilePath.json")))
            .build().getService();
```

***Now it is working.***

***Sample code after fix.***

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translate;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translate.TranslateOption;
import com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translation;

public class QuickstartSample {
   public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
      //Instantiates a client
      //Removed next line
      //Translate translate = TranslateOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
      //Added this line
      Translate translate = TranslateOptions
            .newBuilder()
            .setCredentials(
            ServiceAccountCredentials
                            .fromStream(new FileInputStream(
                                    "YourCredentialFilePath.json")))
            .build().getService();

      //The text to translate
      String text = "Hello, world!";

      //Translates some text into Russian
      Translation translation =
         translate.translate(
              text,
              TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"),
              TranslateOption.targetLanguage("ru"));


      System.out.printf("Text: %s%n", text);
      System.out.printf("Translation: %s%n", translation.getTranslatedText());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key your using does not have the permission to use Translate APIs.

To fix this :

1. Go to [Google Cloud Platform console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)
2. Chose your project from the drop down menu in the top bar
3. Go to `API & Services` > `Library`
4. Search for `Cloud Translation API` and click on it
5. Enable it

   [image: enable api button]
6. Go to `API & Services` > `Credentials`
7. Select the key you are using in your Android App
8. From the menu called `Restrict key`, choose `Cloud Translation API`
9. Save your edit

Now the APIs will work properly.